# How to describe Bipolar-like behaviour in a positive sense?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, etymology

Little bit of background that might seem technical - I'm looking for a name for this common pattern in web design - if you are not logged-in, the homepage shows a marketing landing page. But once you log-in you see a completely different homepage e.g. Facebook shows a sign-up form first - and your feed once you are logged-in.

Design pattern names are typically nouns (for e.g. Visitor Pattern). I like to avoid terms with negative connotation like Bipolar or Split personality.

Some of the names I could think of were:

- Dual Homepage
- Duplex Homepage
- Ambiverted Homepage
- Janus-headed Home

I am not entirely happy with any of these. I am pretty sure I am missing some obvious word to describe someone who behaves in two different ways depending on the context. Appreciate any help in my search to find a proper name.

Comment: How about dynamic ?
or mutable such as with functions.

Comment: The glass is half full.

Comment: Did _ambidextrous_ occur to you?

Comment: Or maybe you should go with _Jekyll and hyde._

Comment: How would the word be used in a piece of natural-sounding prose?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question; requests for help in choosing names is explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

What about double homepage, twin homepages, second homepage, two-step homepage, progressive homepage, two-state homepage, bistable homepage, logging cycle?

Comment: Bistable Homepage sounds appropriate!

Answer (score 0):

The website sounds like the [TARDIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TARDIS) from the popular British sci-fi TV show, Doctor Who, so assuming once logged it is a richer experience, perhaps your pattern could be named a "TARDIS homepage",

View from outside before you log in :

[image: tardis]

but once you login & get inside ...

[image: tardis interior]

PS. Yes, I know naming things is off topic, but I found this one hard to resist.

PPS. These images are copied from Wikipedia, so I assume no copyright issues using them here.

Comment: I like it. But I'm not sure if someone would the get the reference if they haven't watched Doctor Who.

Comment: I would look into copyright issues...

Comment: Do you mean the images? @Greybeard

Comment: I’ve now added a PPS to say from where the images were taken.